# How to use a LIMIT in a SQL Update statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, limit, dbeaver

I have 100,000 nearly identical records in my database and I need to modify one field of half of them.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET schedule_start = '2023-12-19' 
WHERE schedule_start = '2023-12-18' 
  AND email_record ->>'emailId' IN ('44617', '44602', '44603')
LIMIT 50000
```

```
returns a "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit"
  Position: 296"
```

All the documentation I see says that a simple UPDATE statement like mine can be combined with a LIMIT and yet, it does not work. I even tried it without using the email_record qualification (which would require further work by me) but I had the same issue.

So I googled some workarounds. First I tried to break up the statement into 2 by setting the select statement to the value of @id:= but that was also a syntax error. It doesn't know what a TOP or ROWCOUNT is and it was confused by the nested subquery I tried.

Comment: Can you reference where you saw this in the documentation of PostgreSQL? I don't see it in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html